# floated element being pushed down by previous element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/

I have 3 container as part of a responsive page.  In the mobile view they must display in the order- blue, red, green, stacked on top of each other like so..

```
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

which is fine, but in a desktop experience, using the same markup, they must display as shown in the fiddle above, i.e. with the blue and green containers to the right, with a fixed width, and the red container to the left, whereby the red container must span the remaining width of the page, like so:

[image]

I am seeing a problem where at smaller resolutions, the green container will be pushed down, see below

[image]

Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following styles:

```
.test1 {
    padding-right:200px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    margin-right:-200px;
    clear:right;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/10/)

[Example with media query stacking](http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/15/)

Comment: nice.. Ideally I would like all elements floated for other reasons, which you have sorted - thanks!

Comment: what if I want 1px border-bottom for test1

Comment: @NaeemShaikh you add it like you would any other style: http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/14/

Comment: you put `overflow:hidden` in this case. dint you.. Its  really nice solution(also +1 from me), but I would not encourage overflow:hidden just to occupy the children(its not why overflow:hidden is used)

Comment: usually I would add a clearfix but in this case the overflow will cause the same effect - less typing ;)

Answer (score 2):

So far I know, change your html structure like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/3/), if you want to show the divs in different order for desktop as you mentioned in your question,

show different html on desktop, and the one as I linked above for the smaller devices(using mediaQuery).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gw8wank/5/)(and I have seen a similar question on SO before I just cant find it)

```
<!-- for mobile -->

<div class="test1 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
    <div>
    <div class="right blue">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>  
    <div class="right green">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left red">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>

</div>




<!-- for desktop -->

<div class="test1  hidden-xs">
    <div class=" blue">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>  

    <div class=" red">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>
    <div class=" green">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks!  It may be a last resort to use two different html templates, but this would work, even though I am not using bootstrap, I get the concept.

Answer (score 2):

That is a normal behaviour to achieve what you want to do, you can either use:

1- the css calc function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      .right{float:right; clear:right; width:200px}
      .left {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
        float: left;
      }




      .blue{
        background:blue;
      }

      .green{
        background:green;  
      }

      .red{background:red;}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test1">
      <div class="right blue">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
      </div> 

      <div class="left red">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right green">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think css calc isnt supported by IE8, which unfortunately I have to support, thanks @Tambo!

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this solution using percentage widths, and a media query for smaller screen sizes. I hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/ben220/rjef89uw/

```
<div class="blue">
  <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
</div>  

<div class="red">
  <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some     text some text </p>
</div>


* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


.blue {
    background:blue;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.green {
    background:green;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.red {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 580px ) and ( min-width: 1px ) {
    .blue, .green, .red {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```